# create table statement is slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a new table using a sub-set of data from an existing table.

Here is some sample data. This table has 7000 records:

```
create table numbersegment (startnum varchar(35),endnum varchar(35),id_prefix number(10));
insert into numbersegment values('8175290000','8175299999','14108');
insert into numbersegment values('8175300000','8175309999','14108');
insert into numbersegment values('8175310000','8175319999','14108');
insert into numbersegment values('8175320000','8175329999','14108');
insert into numbersegment values('8175330000','8175339999','14108');
```

The User_info table has 35 million records:

```
create table user_info(num varchar(35),subid number(18),custid number(18)); 


insert into user_info values('8175290031',100001234567891111,100001234567891111);
insert into user_info values('8175290032',100001234567891112,100001234567891112);
insert into user_info values('8175290033',100001234567891113,100001234567891113);
insert into user_info values('8175290034',100001234567891114,100001234567891114);
insert into user_info values('8175290035',100001234567891115,100001234567891115);
```

When I execute below SQL it takes around 20 minutes to create customer table

```
 create table customer as 
 select 
   mk.num,
   nm.id_prefix||substr(mk.subid,6) new_sub_id,
   nm.id_prefix||substr(mk.custid,6) new_cust_id
 from user_info mk,
   numbersegment nm 
 where mk.num >=nm.startnum 
 and mk.num    <=nm.endnum;
```

Please suggest fastest way to create this table.

Already tried few things  like parallel execution and Substr to match 1st character.

Comment: Also provide the execution plan so that you can focus where can tune it.

Comment: You're executing arbitrary range searches against a large table; twenty minutes isn't fast but it's not ridiculous. Is this a one-off exercise? If so, just live with it: you've already wasted more time on tuning than you'll save by tuning.

Comment: To be clear: it's the SELECT part of the statement that's slow not the CREATE TABLE. If you had created an empty table and then issued an INSERT INTO ... AS SELECT statement your question would be titled "insert statement is slow"

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion `parallel` with no `logging option` would be faster.

```
create table customer parallel 2 nologging as 
select /*+parallel(source 4) */ *  mk.num,
 nm.id_prefix||substr(mk.subid,6) new_sub_id,
 nm.id_prefix||substr(mk.custid,6) new_cust_id
 from user_info mk,numbersegment nm where mk.num >=nm.startnum and mk.num    <=nm.endnum;
```

For more details:[Miscellaneous Parallel Execution Tuning Tips](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/parallel007.htm)

Comment: this I already tried  with 16 parallel process, after that only its taking 20 mins. Looking for some logical way to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

The select is slow because of the cardinality of user_info table which goes in Cartesian product with the numbersegment table with the clause .

```
         where mk.num >=nm.startnum 
         and mk.num    <=nm.endnum;
```

and you'll have a FULL TABLE SCAN on both tables.

One possible enhancement of the performance consists in creating an index on the user_info.num column, if you didn't already do.

```
  create index USER_INFO_I1 on user_info (num);
```

If you can't do it you could copy the user_info table in another one and create the index **after** the user_info clone table is already populated (otherwise the index recalculation will happen on every insert in the table and will destroy your performance).

Another performance enhancement could be transforming the fields `user_info.num` , `numbersegment.startnum` and `numbersegment.endnum` into `NUMBER` data type (if they are numbers, of course, as they look from your example) .

Also the fields

```
    numbersegment.id_prefix, user_info.subid, user_info.cust_id
```

should be transformed in VARCHAR2, as they look from your query

```
   nm.id_prefix||substr(mk.subid,6) new_sub_id,
   nm.id_prefix||substr(mk.custid,6) new_cust_id
```

but this is not a performance enhancement